# Using self in pytest parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

How can I use attributes in `parametrize` in pytest with tests organized in classes?

```
import pytest

class TestA:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def set_up(self):
        self.field1 = "field1"
        self.field2 = "field2"

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("field", (self.field1, self.field2))
    def test_print_field(self, field):
        print(field, flush=False)
```

I'm getting `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Comment: Why are you doing that? you should define attributes OR test parameters (if they are the same), it doesn't really make sense to do both.

Comment: What if I want to reuse attribute at many tests and if fields are not constants?

Comment: You cannot use `self` in a decorator, as it is read at load time and no instance exists at that time. You could use [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best practice but here's something that can do the work:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("field", ("field1", "field2"))
def test_print_field(self, field):
    print(eval(f"self.{field}"), flush=False)
```

You might want to use fixtures instead to set up and tear down.

Comment: This just results in `TypeError: TestA.test_print_field() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field'`